# Spring security - how come I cannot login into my application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm having a somewhat embarrassing problem trying to login to my application.

My Spring security `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` is defined as:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(http);
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()

        .authorizeRequests()
            // I admit that this section needs some work
            .antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/benefit/*", "/client/*", "/contract/*", "/role/*", "/structure/*", "/term/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/benefit/*", "/client/*", "/contract/*", "/role/*", "/structure/*", "/term/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")

            .and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .and()
                .csrf()
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
}
```

The application loads up nicely and goes to the `/login` page. But when I try to log with the user `master` and provide the correct password, it simply returns to the `/login` page.

My login controller is:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserProfileService userProfileService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Principal principal) {
        return principal != null ? "home/homeSignedIn" : "home/homeNotSignedIn";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){    
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("roles")
    public List<UserProfile> initializeProfiles() {
        return userProfileService.findAll();
    }
}
```

`User`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends BasePojo {

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="sso_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String ssoId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="password", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="state", nullable=false)
    private String state=UserState.ACTIVE.getState();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "hrm_user_user_profile", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", referencedColumnName="id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_profile", referencedColumnName="id") })
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles;
```

`UserProfile`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profile")
public class UserProfile extends BasePojo {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="type", length=15, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String type = UserProfileType.USER.getUserProfileType();

    // Constructor used only for initial data loading, not used after
    public UserProfile() {
    }

    // Constructor used only for initial data loading, not used after
    public UserProfile(String type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

`UserState`:

```
public enum UserState {

    LOCKED("state.locked"),
    INACTIVE("state.inactive"),
    ACTIVE("state.active");

    String state;

    private UserState(final String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }
```

I'm lost here. Can I get some help?

Comment: Have you enabled DEBUG logging for Spring Security? What does it say?

Comment: I did managed to enable DEBUG logging, but I'm overwhelmed with too much stack trace and trying to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: Two outputs caught my attention:
`SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: ACF7917E21FC1061F792C959AD0E1323; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'`

Comment: and: `SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are getting the user authenticated correctly. However, your /login POST handler method, needs to make sure that the subsequent requests have either a cookie or a token in its headers.

This way, the rules set by you as below, will be applied

```
        .antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/benefit/*", "/client/*", "/contract/*", "/role/*", "/structure/*", "/term/*").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/", "/home/*", "/alert/*", "/scheduler/*", "/agent/*", "/ftp/*", "/smtp/*", "/sql/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/benefit/*", "/client/*", "/contract/*", "/role/*", "/structure/*", "/term/*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
```

For instance, lets say user is trying to access /home. Since the user is not authenticated, he is redirected to the login page. The user enters his username and password and is authenticated now. Once this is done, spring security by default will redirect the user to the return URL /home. By default, spring security will add a cookie to the response so that every subsequent request contains that cookie in the request. I believe this is not happening in your case. I would like to know more about your spring security configurations. How is the user authentication taking place? Is it an in memory authentication? or Data source authentication?

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I had already solved the issue. During my (re) leaning curve of Spring, I managed to unadvertdly set the user status hard-coded and, when I tried to refactor it, I got lost. I accepted your answer for you took the time trying to help out!

Comment: I had the exact same problem. To be clear for future readers I had a logic bug in my `UserDetails#isAccountNonLocked` method. So my `UserDetailsService` impl *was* correctly finding my user object, and the password match *was* succeeding, however Spring Security at some point must perform a bunch of checks on the user/principal it is about to return, and one of them is that `isAccountNonLocked` method. My bug was incorrectly returning `false` when calling that method, which is the same as saying `isAccountLocked == true`...it was a double-negative bug...doh!!!